# IFrame in an ASP.net app

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have an ASP.net website (a DNN app).  User can log in using the usual-login.

Now I need to create an application that is completely separate from the existing website, yet it needs to appear as part of the existing website. The proposed solution right now to this is using an IFrame.

The problem with this however, is that the app needs to have a security context - in other words, know who is logged in and what role they are assigned.

Is this possible in an IFrame?  From what I have found so far, the IFrame is "dumb" ie restricted from the rest of the webpage.  If this is the case, is there an alternative to using an IFrame?

Greg

Comment: Will both applications be hosted on the same domain name? (it matters for the security)

Comment: Yes, they will be on the same domain name, For example:  MainSite.com and App.MainSite.com

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Also, what is the rationale behind them needing to be separate applications?

Comment: The rational is that the basic website is currently a Dot Net Nuke website, and the second one is based on the user ordering reports which are data driven from back end databases. It's a mix of javascript and asp.net. But it is a completely separate project.  The project owner does not want to combine the two into one code base.  There are two different groups working on them.

Comment: It uses the DNN authentication, I think that is just the usual asp.net forms authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

create two public local variables in DNN code behind Page Where You want implement iframe like

```
 public string loginuser;
 public string Role;
```

set current logging user details in this two variables like username and role and if not any user logging then its value blank

in aspx page where iframe exists

```
<iframe src="http://App.MainSite.com?currentuser=<%= loginuser%>&role=<%= Role%>"></iframe>
```

Read query string values on your App.MainSite.com page load event

```
if (Request.QueryString["currentuser"!=null && Request.QueryString["currentuser"!="") {
    //Current User
}

if (Request.QueryString["role"!=null && Request.QueryString["role"!="") {
    //Current User role
}
```